# Print result right after each unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

---

I'm working on a small script to run python unit test and I do it like this:

```
def run_test(suite):
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    start = time.time()
    result = runner.run(suite)
    end = time.time()
    log_test_results(result, str(end-start))
```

And in log_test_results I write out all passed/failed tests. The problem with this is that I have to wait for the test suite to finish before I can see if any test have passed/failed. Is there any way to print the result right after each assert inside the TestCase instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set verbosity for TextTestRunner, then after each test case method finish, you'll see the pass/fail result.

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I looked for. But just a follow-up question so I can see if there are any other way to do it. Say for example I want to log this myself in a custom logger, is there any way to collect this information myself, log it and then print instead of having TextTestRunner print it?

Comment: @user1776562 You can pass a stream variable. e.g unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2, stream=sys.stderr), Instead of default stderr, you can pass your custom stream to it, and then fetch output from the stream.